# What is the difference between class: 'item' and :class => "item" in Ruby on Rails? Which style should I use?

Tags: ruby

I am pretty new to Rails and I'm working with a new code base that sometimes uses two different syntax for the same thing.

```
class: 'item'
```

vs

```
:class => "item"
```

However, I have have not been able to find what the difference is or which style I should use as best-practice.

I assume that it has something to do with the Rails version. We are planning to move to Rails 6. Can somebody shed some insight on this for me?

Comment: It's not a Rails thing, it's how Ruby works.

Comment: Take your pick. Keep in mind that you can only use `a: b` if the key, here `:a`, is a symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does not concern Rails, it's a pure Ruby syntax.

The basic answer is that the syntax

```
:class => "item"
```

is simply from the older version of Ruby — mainly pre-1.9.

Ruby versions 1.9 and newer all support the new syntax, which is more compact and is borrowed from the JSON format.

I noticed you used double quotes in one example and single quotes in another. In Ruby we try to use single quotes whenever we have a string without interpolation, and double quotes when we use interpolation.

Therefore both of your examples should be using single quotes.

Having said that, this is a style guide that is hotly debated. See this link for more info:

https://dockyard.com/blog/ruby/2012/02/16/single-quotes-or-double-quotes

Comment: I appreciate you answering the question and going into more detail regarding the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing, both create a key/value pair. Where the key is the [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Symbol.html) `:class` and the value is the [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html) `'item'`.

Normally you create a key/value pair using the `=>` syntax. `{'key' => 'value'}` (here both the key and value are a String) however, since a symbol already starts with a symbol they've added some syntactic sugar later on.

The `:` at the end of a symbol denotes both that the key is a symbol and that it concerns a key/value pair. For symbols `{:key => 'value'}` is the old syntax and `{key: 'value'}` is the newer variant. The examples given here are [hash literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes) but this also applies when calling methods. `some_method(key: 'value')`

Answer (score 0):

They're the same.

Consider this:

```
{a: 1}    # => {:a=>1}
{:a => 1} # => {:a=>1}
```

Use either form of assigning the value as Ruby is happy. The shorter form was added as a convenience, not because it was any better or was preferable.